# How PUT file into FTP with Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ftp, put

I have a local file and I need to upload into a remote FTP (not SFTP) server with login.

Please, how could I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There seems to be a lot of information missing regarding your use case, infrastructure, remote FTP server capabilities, etc. Can you add more context and description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your use case, infrastructure, capabilities of the remote FTP server, etc., there might be several options.

If you like to use plain File Transfer Protocol (FTP) over TCP/21

- A [Custom Module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html) like [`ftp` - Transfers files and directories from or to FTP servers](https://github.com/melmorabity/ansible-ftp/blob/master/ftp.py)
- The [`shell` module – Execute shell commands on targets](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html) with `curl`

  ```yaml
  - name: Transfer file to FTP server
    shell:
      cmd: "curl --silent --user {{ ansible_user }}:{{ ansible_password }} ftp://ftp.example.com -T {{ fileToTransfer }}"
    register: result
  ```

If the FTP server software has additionally HTTP server capabilities implemented

- The module [`uri` - Interacts with webservices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html) with parameter `method: PUT`

  ```yaml
  - name: Upload content
     local_action:
       module: uri
       url: "http://ftp.example.oom"
       method: PUT
       url_username: "{{ ansible_user }}"
       url_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
       body: "{{ lookup('file', fileToTransfer) }}"
     register: result
  ```

  *... not sure if this would work, haven't tested such setup yet and there is still information missing*

**Other Q&A**

- [How to upload one file by FTP from command line?](https://superuser.com/a/323268/754490)
- [How to upload a file to FTP via `curl` but from `stdin`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/527718/266568)

**Further Documentation**

- [`curl --upload-file`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--upload-file)
- [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959)

Answer (score 0):

By sending commands to the ftp Client command - I use `lftp` in the following example:

```
    - name: Upload file
      shell: |
        lftp -u {{ ansible_user }},{{ ansible_pass }} ftp.example.com << EOF
        cd folder
        put yourfile.txt
        exit
        EOF
```